# ts-node cannot find module typescript

Tags: typescript, docker, package.json, nestjs, ts-node

I'm deploying a dockerized typescript app on AWS. When I run the app container I get a ts-node error `Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'` which is not clear to me because `typescript` is defined as a devDependency. 
These are my `package.json` dependencies

```
{
 "name": "app-server",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "description": "description",
 "author": "Marcello Bardus",
 "license": "MIT",
 "scripts": {
   "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
   "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
   "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
   "start:dev": "nodemon",
   "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
   "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && tsc",
   "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
   "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
   "test": "jest",
   "test:watch": "jest --watch",
   "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
   "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
"test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@nestjs/common": "^5.4.0",
   "@nestjs/core": "^5.4.0",
   "@nestjs/typeorm": "^5.3.0",
   "@types/mongoose": "^5.3.18",
   "elliptic": "^6.4.1",
   "mongoose": "^5.4.14",
   "object-hash": "^1.3.1",
   "pg": "^7.8.0",
   "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
   "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
   "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
   "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
   "sha2": "^1.0.2",
   "typeorm": "^0.2.13",
   "typescript": "^3.0.1"
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "@nestjs/testing": "^5.1.0",
  "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
  "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
  "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
  "@types/supertest": "^2.0.5",
  "jest": "^23.5.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
  "prettier": "^1.14.2",
  "supertest": "^3.1.0",
  "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
  "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
  "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
  "tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
  "typescript": "^3.0.1",
  "tslint": "5.11.0"
},
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
"rootDir": "src",
"testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
"coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
"testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

And the Dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g ts-node nodemon
RUN npm install
RUN npm install typescript

EXPOSE 8085

CMD ["nodemon", "."]
```

I suppose that `typescript` is installed locally once the container has been built but it's not. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: try `npm i -g typescript` in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Didn’t help, but thanks anyway.

Comment: no problem. Can you include the full `package.json` __in your answer__?

Comment: Can you try installing `ts-node@^7.0.1` globally? This also matches the version in your `package.json`. Might be related to this issue: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/765

Comment: @molamk Sadly, it's not possible to use ts-node with a globally installed typescript at the moment, see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/707#issuecomment-457448149

Comment: `ts-node` is not really meant for production use. You should transpile your `Typescript` code into `JavaScript`, then call `node startingPoint.js`

Comment: @molamk I agree. In nest.js, you can use `npm run start:prod` which compiles the typescript and then runs the compiled javascript.

Comment: Ts-nose is being installed globally, I tried to install typescript locally as in the issue but it doesn’t solve my problem

Comment: package.json updated

Comment: Is there a reason why you install ts-node, nodemon globally instead of just installing everything locally with npm install and then running `CMD [ “npm”, “run”, “start:prod” ]`, (or `start:dev` if you really want nodemon to run)?

Comment: yes, when I install nodemon locally the app container throws "nodemon\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: @KimKern `npm run start:prod` throws `app_1           | > rimraf dist && tsc
app_1           | 
app_1           | sh: 1: rimraf: not found
app_1           | npm ERR! file sh
app_1           | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app_1           | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
app_1           | npm ERR! syscall spawn
app_1           | npm ERR! app-server@0.0.0 prestart:prod: rimraf dist && tsc`

Comment: Weird. Sounds like none of your local dependencies are being installed. What does it say when you remove rimraf dist && from your prestart:prod script?

Comment: When I remove it, it throws `Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main.js'`. Honestly I don't know how typescript is compiled maybe should I change dist/ to /build?

Comment: `tsc` is the typescript compiler and compiles the javascript into `dist` as defined in your `tsconfig.json`. On your local machine, `npm run start:prod` works?

Comment: No, throws cannot find module dist/main.ts. It seams that the typescript is not even compiled. What's weird is that when I run a docker container on my local machine using docker desktop everything works fine ...

Answer (score 22):

Finally, I got ts-node to work using npx:

1. Install typescript globally:

   ```
   npm i typescript -g
   ```
2. Go to your project directory and link typescript to the project:

   ```
   cd <my-project>

   npm link typescript
   ```
3. Execute ts-node using npx:

   ```
   npx ts-node <your-ts-script>.ts
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I have installed typescript globally using - `npm i typescript -g` 

Still getting the issue - **Error: Cannot find module ‘@types/node/package.json‘**

Then this helped me to resolve the issue - `sudo npm install -D tslib @types/node`

After this, I was able to run my script file using either of these -

```
npx ts-node <script-file>.ts
```

OR

```
ts-node <script-file>.ts
```

You will get detailed explanation on the official **npmjs** website - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Comment: `npm i @types/node` did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use `ts-node` and `nodemon` as starting point of your application, then explicitly define them in `package.json` dependencies.

Then `RUN npm install --production`

They'll be accesible in `node_modules/.bin/`

```sh
~/foo/node_modules/.bin

> ls
is-ci@    nodetouch@  rc@      ts-node@         ts-node-transpile-only@
nodemon@  nopt@       semver@  ts-node-script@  ts-script@
```

Then you can run `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon` or `npx nodemon` as your Docker `CMD`.

> `npx`
>
> Executes  either from a local node_modules/.bin, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for  to run.

source: [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx)

---

Tip to improve your `Dockerfile`, [the right way](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) to cache `node_modules`.

```
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app
```

> Note that, rather than copying the entire working directory, we are only copying the package.json file. This allows us to take advantage of cached Docker layers.

Then copy app files

```
COPY . /usr/src/app
```

Don't forget `.dockerignore` `node_modules`.